# Using Google Tag Manager with Xamarin Google Analytics component results in error

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to implement tracking using Google Tag Manager in an iOS app built with Xamarin, but I fail to get a container. I end up with this error in my application log: "GoogleTagManager error: notifier must be non-nil".

I used the [Google Tag Manager Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v3/) guide on the Google Developers website to fabricate this code piece.

```
public class TagManagerService : NSObject, ITAGContainerOpenerNotifier
{
    TAGContainer container;
    readonly TAGDataLayer dataLayer;
    readonly TAGManager tagManager;

    public TagManagerService()
    {
        tagManager = TAGManager.GetInstance;
        dataLayer = tagManager.DataLayer;

        #if DEBUG
        tagManager.Logger.LogLevel = TAGLoggerLogLevelType.Verbose;
        #endif

        TAGContainerOpener.OpenContainer(Constants.TagManagerContainerId, tagManager, TAGOpenType.PreferFresh, 0, this);
    }

    public void ContainerAvailable(TAGContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This bug was fixed on latest version of Google Analytics library 3.0.10.3 [according to Xamarin Dev team](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32172/using-google-tag-manager-with-google-analytics-component).

You can check the [library page here](https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleanalytics) for more instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do take it further for enhanced ecommerce implementation, which you should be doing if wants to strength app conversion, check out [my blog post](http://www.bigmegacode.com/xamarin-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-ios/) on how to do it.

The key is on the proper object structure for nested values on gtm like below sample code

```
NSMutableArray products = new NSMutableArray ();
        if (LIST != null && LIST.Count > 0) {
            foreach (var b in LIST) {
                NSDictionary p = new NSDictionary ("name", b.name, "id", b.id,
                    "price", b.total, "category", b.category, "quantity", b.quantity);

                products.Add (NSObject.FromObject (p));
            }

            NSDictionary actionField = new NSDictionary ("id", "value", "revenue", "value", "tax", "value", "shipping", "value", "coupon","value");
            NSDictionary purchase = new NSDictionary ("purchase", new NSDictionary ("products", NSObject.FromObject(products) , "actionField", NSObject.FromObject(actionField)));

            NSDictionary data = new NSDictionary ("event", "purchase", "ecommerce", NSObject.FromObject(purchase));

            manager.DataLayer.Push (data);
        }
```